# How can I have a tabular flush with the margins?

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

Consider the following:

```
\documentclass{article}

\setlength\parindent{0pt}

\begin{document}
content \hfill content

\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
  one   & two \\
  three & four
\end{tabular*}

content \hfill content
\end{document}
```

> [image: output]

How can I remove the whitespace at either side of the `tabular`?

Comment: Of course I find the problem as soon as I guts up and post: while I'm not specifying to display them, LaTeX is leaving room for separator lines.  Adding `\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}` solves this issue.  ('Doh!)

Comment: While it won't make a difference in the present case, it's better in general to insert `@{}` in front of the first column and after the final column to eliminate the extra whitespace. I.e., one would write something like `\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{}l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r@{}}`. One reason this it better is because it works with all other tabular-type environments, viz., `tabular`, `tabularx`, `tabulary`, etc.

Comment: @Mico Your right.  Sounds like an answer (before the potential closing I started…) :-)

Comment: Related/duplicate: [Column and row padding in tables](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31672/5764)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While `\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}` will do the job in your example, it's better in general to insert `@{}` in front of the first column and after the final column to eliminate the whitespace (in the amount of `\tabcolsep`) that LaTeX inserts by default in these locations.

For the case of your example, you'd write

```
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{} l @{\extracolsep{\fill}} r @{}}
```

instead of

```
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{l @{\extracolsep{\fill}} r}
```

The approach based on inserting `@{}` particles is better because it works not only with `tabular*` but also with `tabular`, `tabularx`, `tabulary`, and so on.